# Modify the behavior of a draggable after drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The elements are draggable in both directions (x and y) before being dropped.
After the drop they should only be draggable in one direction (y axis).
I tried removing the class with draggability in both directions, then adding a new class with draggability in one direction. However this is not working: after the drop and after the new class is added the elements can still be dragged in both directions. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: The entire code is 220 lines long. I'll try to filter out the parts that are relevant and post them. But thank you @simonzack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the `drop` event from the droppable container. Fire off the destroy to kill the draggable.

```
$("#bar").draggable("destroy");
```

Re-bind it, indicating that the axis should only be Y

```
$('#bar').draggable({axis: 'y'});
```

Putting it all together:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        if ($(draggable).data('dropped')) {
            //this happened during only the "Y" axis constraint
            //do whatever
        } else {
            $(draggable).draggable('destroy');
            $(draggable).data('dropped', true)
            $(draggable).draggable({
                axis: 'y'
            });
        }
    }
});
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

[In motion](http://jsfiddle.net/rLJXR/)